# HP Reverb G2 buttons not working in Unreal Engine 4 after controllers update?

Tags: unreal-engine4, windows-mixed-reality

I use the G2 to develop VR software in UE4 version 4.26.

we noticed that the facebuttons on either controller stopped working on Monday.  at first we thought it was something I did in Unreal, but I can't get to the root of the problem, and all the other input is registering correctly (grab, trigger).
in some older versions that we know worked, we built again to test, now aren't working either.
beginning to think it's a bug in a controller update from Monday.
are there any known bugs?

*Edit: 3/15*
@Hernando-MSFT
After significant time spent on this I found out what the problem was.
The Windows Mixed Reality plugin in UE4 was preventing the G2's buttons from registering input.  I disabled the plugin and then when opening the UE4 app it would run in OpenXR instead of WMR and now the buttons register.
Why that only started happening last week; and why the G2's buttons would not register on its native platform (WMR) is very mysterious.

Comment: You mentioned that it might be a bug in a controller update from Monday, so could you please clarify the version number of the current controller? And which the version worked before.

Comment: Hello @Hernando-MSFT,

In further testing I have swung back to thinking it might be something in my code in UE4.  I can't rule out a bug in the software update just yet, but I will be investigating the problem further tomorrow or Monday.  I will post again when I have more information.

Thanks for your reply.